# Не работает ТГ Бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Работаю с библиотекой AioGram Делаю бота задающего рандомные вопросы. Создал функцию которая из 65 вопросов рандомно выбирает 1 с помощью кучи `elif` Но почему то ничего не работает, при запуске бота:

`if message.text == "" or message.text == "" or or message.text == "":`

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def Poslanie(message : types.Message):
    if message.text == '' or message.text == '' or or message.text == '':
        await message.reply(' - Самый говношный стикер')

@dp.message_handler(commands["RunDenVikIm"])
async def command_start(message : types.Message):
    Random()
    Queshes()

@dp.message_handler(commands['Quesh'])
async def Q(message : types.Message):
    await message.answer(Quesh)
```

Функция `Random()` это выбор рандомного числа. А функция `Qeshes()` это выбор вопроса по этому самому числу. При этом ошибка выходит на строке с другим действием(

**Буду очень благодарен если напишите в чём проблема!**

Comment: Два OR подряд - нельзя так

Comment: сделай так `if message.text in ["", "", ""]: ...`  или так `if "" in message.text: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего будет сделать так:

```
@dp.message_handler(text_contains='')
async def bademoji(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(' - Самый говношный стикер')
```